# Project Euler #8, I can't figure out why my code gives absurdly high values

Tags: c++, c

Recently, I started with [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) and so far it's been going well, but I went on to the 8th problem, and have been stuck on it ever since.

In the problem there is a 1000-digit number and we need to find the greatest product of the adjacent 13 numbers.
The number is here:

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

My code goes as follows:

```
int main() {
char str[] = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
unsigned long long int  product,maxPrev=0;
int i = 0, j = 0;
product = (str[i] - 48) *(str[i+1] -48) *(str[i+2] -48) *(str[i+3] -48) *(str[i+4] -48) *(str[i+5]-48) *(str[i+6]-48) *(str[i+7] -48) *(str[i+8] -48) *(str[i+9]-48) *(str[i+10]-48) *(str[i+11]-48) *(str[i+12]-48);
maxPrev = product;
for(i=0;i<=986;i++){
       product= (str[i] - 48) *(str[i+1] -48) *(str[i+2] -48) *(str[i+3] -48) *(str[i+4] -48) *(str[i+5]-48) *(str[i+6]-48) *(str[i+7] -48) *(str[i+8] -48) *(str[i+9]-48) *(str[i+10]-48) *(str[i+11]-48) *(str[i+12]-48);
       if(product>maxPrev){
               maxPrev = product;
                        }                     
}
printf("\n%llu",maxPrev);
getchar();
return 0;
```

}

So far, I noticed that somewhere in the code, an overflow occurs and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Did you check if product is going upper than unsignd long long int maximum possible value? May that causes the problem

Comment: If I put the long long int, then some products gets negative (I really don't know why), while in unsigned long long int, they overflow to the maximum positive value.

Comment: @George But how is that possible, if the 13 adjacent numbers would be all nines, it gives us the value of 9^13 = 2.541e+12, and the maximum size of unsigned long long int is very much higher than that.

Comment: @Sajad nope nope and nope you really shouldn't use `abs` not here at least.

Comment: @Sajad I think that they occur because of a overflow.

Comment: i've just tested your code and, honestly, it seems to work just fine

Comment: @a.costa Really? I've used both 2 online c compilers and Dev-C++ compiler and nothing worked for me.

Comment: @Sajad The negative numbers in this case come from type overflow, basically you shouldn't need to get the abs value, and I see nothing in his code that indicates the abs value of a negative value would be logically correct.

Comment: better go through the array once and subtract all values by `'0'` so that you don't need to subtract again and again

Comment: "I noticed that somewhere in the code, an overflow occurs"  --> I find it curious that OP did not post the result seen.  Unexpected results, even if wrong, offer clues to the problem.

Comment: C++ or C?  Your code is one or the other; don't use both tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `(str[i] - 48)` evaluates to an `int`, not an `unsigned long long`.

You have to cast the expression

```
product = (unsigned long long)(str[i] - '0') *(str[i+1] - '0') *(str[i+2] - '0') *(str[i+3] - '0') *(str[i+4] - '0') *(str[i+5] - '0') *(str[i+6] - '0') *(str[i+7] - '0') *(str[i+8] - '0') *(str[i+9] - '0') *(str[i+10] - '0') *(str[i+11] - '0') *(str[i+12] - '0');
```

Also you should use `'0'` instead of `48`.

Instead of this line you can use another loop

```
product = 1;
for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
{
    if (!isdigit(str[i + j]) || str[i + j] == '0')
    {
        product = 0;
        break;
    }
    product *= str[i + j] - '0';
}
```

to calculate the product. In this case the cast is not necessary, because `product` has already the correct type.

Comment: Also, you should write a function to do this (or possibly notice that having calculated the initial product, you can calculate the remaining ones by dividing by the number you just dropped and multiplying by the number you just included).

Comment: D'oh!  No - it won't will it!

Comment: Ah, ha!  But if digit is zero, then you can restart again just after the zero with a newly calculated product (... and searching for a string of 13 non-zero digits).  There is no point considering any of the 13 products that contain a zero - they will all be zero, and we could just initialize maxPrev to zero.

Comment: @MislavJanjić in this case you should insert your `"/*that huge number */"` in your question code.

Comment: @MislavJanjić combining your code with my answer gives a result: http://ideone.com/bvh88Q

Comment: @mch That is correct. Then what was the real problem with my code? Was it the missing cast?

Comment: Yes.  That is what we have told you ?three? times!  `int * int` is of type int.  `unsigned long long * int` is of type unsigned long long.

Comment: @MislavJanjić yes, just adding the cast solved the problem: http://ideone.com/nnPFc8 . So there is no other error in your code.

Comment: @mch But when I tried with the cast, I got the same result as before. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT2: Explanation of the problem

Your issue was that when you computed `product = A * B * C * D * ...` your intermediate results (A, B, ...) were of type int by default. The C standard states that multiplying two int's produces another int, it won't automatically upgrade itself to a bigger type if the value is too big. As such, the code was the same as:

```
int int_product = A * B * C * D * ...;
product = (unsigned long long int) int_product;
```

Which shows clearly why there would be such an error. To prevent the compiler from treating the intermediate results as ints you have 2 options:

1. Never store the intermediate results in the first place.

This is the option I present below, where you never actually multiply two integers together, rather you always multiply the `unsigned long long int` with an `int`. The reason this works is that the C standard states that the `int` will be promoted to match the `unsigned long long int`. In general when there are two types of different sizes, the compiler will tend to promote the smaller one to match the larger one if necessary rather than the other way around. Based on this we can construct:

2. Convert one of the intermediate results to the appropriate sign to force integer promotion.

This is the option presented in the other answer. By changing the statement to:

```
product = (unsigned long long int) A * B * C * D * ...;
```

You force the coercion of `A * B` to be `unsigned long long int` which forces `(A * B) * C` to be the same, etc all the way until the end of the values.

Unfortunately very soon you will find PE questions where the numbers really are too big for an unsigned long long int to store. In this case you will need bignums. When I did my PE spree I used the gnu multiprecision library, [gmp](https://gmplib.org/). It is fast and relatively easy to use.

---

The largest value 13 adjacent digits multiplied together can have is 9^13 which is about 2 500 000 000 000. That may very well be larger than your unsigned long long int can hold. You should check this manually by just computing 9^13 and seeing if your value can hold it.

If that is not the problem, make sure that -48 is correct. For that reason I would switch to -'0'. I would also check to make sure that the number has no newlines/spaces in it. If your string contains newlines or spaces then subtracting '0' from it will indeed (correctly) produce negative values. If you copy-paste that block directly into the code, you will be dropping newlines (ascii code 10) and getting negatives.

tl;dr: You probably have non-digits in your string, remove them and it should work.

EDIT: Your problem *is* integer promotion. You need to ensure that at every step you are using an unsigned long long int. As such, use that 'j' variable you created as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 986; i++) {
    product = (str[i] - '0');
    for (j = 1; j <= 13; j++) {
         product *= str[i + j] - '0';
    }
    // ...
}
```

That way you never try to multiply things in anything other than an unsigned long long int.

Modifying your code that way I was able to produce the result expected from PE.

Comment: unsigned long long int has to be able to hold 2\*\*64-1 (it is permitted to hold more), that is approximately 18 000 000 000 000 000 000 - which is *vastly* larger than 9\*\*13.  (Consider that 16\*\*13 == 2\*\*52.)

Comment: Yep, usigned long long int can't store the 9^13, I really thought it could. I just tried it on a random variable, and it gives me the overflowed value

Comment: @MislavJanjić: Yes it can.  The problem is that you calculate the product as a signed integer (which overflows), and *then* convert to `ull`.  You need to calculate the product as `ull` in the first place.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Actually it only *should* be able to store that much, if supported. Most compilers are more than happy to not truly support unsigned long long ints and instead drop them down to shorter ints. Either way, I believe the problem to be in the newlines in the string, causing '\n' - 48, which is negative, to be stored in the ull and causing underflow. I suspect that his ull really can hold 9^13, but it is still worth checking that.

Comment: @LambdaBeta But I've rechecked the number almost 10 times, and haven't found anything other than a number.

Comment: Do you have the newlines in the string? Because they will be given the ascii value 10 in your code (most likely). Also check the integer promotion, you do need the cast on your multiplications as above.

Comment: @LambdaBeta I've checked for newlines, but haven't found any, I edited the question with the number in string. And with the cast it still doesn't work.

Comment: @LambdaBeta: The C99 standard (which the C++ standard references) says that ULLONG_MAX is the maximum value an unsigned long long can hold, and it shall have a value of *at least* 18446744073709551615.  Any compiler while doesn't support that is not a C++ compiler.  Can you point me at one which doesn't use 64 bits for long long?

Comment: @MartinBonner many compilers still default to c89 where ULLONG_MAX is still up for debate iirc. I could be wrong though. I know for sure that some compilers straight up don't support unsigned long long ints (I have a 16-bit embedded compiler that just refuses to compile them, but silently converts them to 32-bit unsigned ints instead).

Comment: In the context C++98 is more relevant.  C++98 compilers that refuse to compile `ull` are fine.  C++98 compilers that accept it, but treat it as uint32_t are very seriously evil.  I accept that there are some very seriously evil embedded compilers out there.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, so even when the standard says something, I often double check it, especially with unusual uses like `unsigned long long int` (and long floating types especially) because its quick and easy and often finds other bugs. EG: When OP checked if their type could store 9^13 they found that it *couldn't*, which actually just proved that it was an integer coercion problem. They're going to run into more similar issues in future PE challenges soon if they doesn't fully understand what went wrong.

Comment: @LambdaBeta Can you elaborate then?

Comment: @MislavJanjić Elaboration added to question via edit.

Answer (score 0):

OP code is certainly having overflow due to `int` multiplication rather than using a wider type like `long long` or `unsigned long long` [@mch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615137/2410359).

Yet I see the problem may be more *efficiently* solved by forming the first product and then dividing out the eldest digits and the multiplying by the new digit.  Special handling of `0` digits allows the digit scanning to skip ahead 13 digits and need not cause a divide-by-0.

I now see this is part of [@Martin Bonner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614903/project-euler-8-i-cant-figure-out-why-my-code-gives-absurdly-high-values/40615942#comment68464268_40615137) comments.  So will make it wiki.

Sample code: [cpp.sh/9vuif](http://cpp.sh/9vuif)